# Characterization of Absolute Continuity of Measures

Tags: measure-theory

Let (X,Σ) be a measurable space and μ,ν two (positive) measures defined in Σ. We say that ν is absolute continuous with respect to μ ( and we write ν<<μ) if the following holds: 
$$ ( \forall E\in Σ , μ(E)=0) \Rightarrow (ν(E)=0) $$ Now, if ν is also a finite measure then we have an ε-δ characterization of the above definition which is:

$ ν<<μ \Leftrightarrow \forall \epsilon\ >0, \exists δ=δ(\epsilon)>0 ,$such as $\forall E\in Σ,$ with $μ(E)<δ$ we have $ν(E)<\epsilon $.

I am interested  in the case where ν is not a finite measure and so the above characterization is not valid. Suppose that we are at the measurable space $ (\Bbb N, \mathcal{P} (\Bbb N)) $ and we define two measures as following:
$$
μ(E)= \sum_{n\in E} \displaystyle{\frac{1}{2^n}}
$$

$$
ν(E)= 
\begin{cases}
card(E),  & \text{if E is finite} \\
\infty, & \text{if E is infinite}
\end{cases}
$$Then, of course ν is absolute continuous w.r.t μ, but the ε-δ condition must fail in this case.
$$
\text{If we take},\epsilon =1 ,\text{then for all $n$ $\in \Bbb N$} ,\text{we can find $E_n:= \{n,n+1,n+2,....\} $},\text{such as} 
$$
$$ μ(E_{n})= \sum_{j \in E_{n}} \displaystyle{\frac{1}{2^j}}= \sum_{j=n}^\infty \displaystyle{\frac{1}{2^j}}= \displaystyle{\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}} < \displaystyle{\frac{1}{2^{n-2}}} \\
\text{but}, ν(Ε_{n})=card(E_{n})=card(\{n,n+1,....\})=\infty >1 $$ and so the ε-δ condition is not true. Is this correct or i'm missing something? 
Thanks you in advance.

Comment: You are not missing anything. Your argument is fine.